# Programmatically check VAT number is valid in checkout page magento 2.3.X?

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, vat

I want to Programmatically check VAT number is valid in checkout page magento 2.3.X whether using of event or plugin.

Please provide any suggestion to achieve it.

Comment: There are ready made extensions out there that do this already https://swissuplabs.com/tax-vat-for-magento-2.html whilst I understand you want to write this yourself it's not a small task and your time is more valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please Follow below steps for validate VAT Number in checkout on selection of shipping country
>
> Note : Magento is checking VAT(tax) Validation only for European countries.

**1. Vendorname\Modulename\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector">
        <plugin name="Vendorname_Modulename_Commontaxcollector" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollectorPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollectorPlugin.php**

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;

class CommonTaxCollectorPlugin
{
    public function afterMapItem(\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector $subject, $result
    ){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $vat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Vat');
    $Checkout = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $addressInformation = $Checkout->getQuote();
    $scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
    $countries_list = $scopeConfig->getValue('general/country/eu_countries');
    $country = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
    $VatId = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getVatId();
    if(preg_match("/{$country}/i", $countries_list)) {
        if($VatId){
            $result1 = $vat->checkVatNumber($country,$VatId);
            if($result1->getIsValid()){
                // Valid VAT Number
            }else{
               //Invalid VAT Number
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working !! you shouldn't use $objectManger :)

Comment: Were you able to remove vat also, if vat number is valid?

Comment: you can unset vat from $result variable under valid VAT number condition

Comment: @DivyeshRana can you please explain? or provide code also?

Comment: @DivyeshRana  can you provide code please ??

Answer (score 1):

VAT Validation is native in Magento 2.3.x:  https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/tax/vat.html

You can find the configurations, Validation, and how to configure VAT ID Validation.

> In certain business-to-business transactions, VAT is not assessed. Magento can validate a customer’s VAT ID to ensure that VAT is assessed (or not assessed) properly. See VAT ID Validation: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/tax/vat-validation.html
>
> VAT ID Validation automatically calculates the required tax for B2B transactions that take place within the European Union (EU), based on the merchant and customer locale. Magento performs VAT ID validation using the web services of the European Commission server.

Comment: will this work for guest users also? And remove their vat from total, if vat is validated?

Comment: Yes it works both flows @ArsalanUlHaq

Comment: Yes. THanks it worked!