# Magento2.3- Remove vat if vat number is present on checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, tax, vat, remove

I want to remove `vat` from checkout on run-time, If `vat` number field has some value.

I am able to validate vat number on run-time on checkout (via this link [Programmatically check VAT number is valid in checkout page magento 2.3.X?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286193/programmatically-check-vat-number-is-valid-in-checkout-page-magento-2-3-x#comment438601_289284) ) but didn't know how to remove vat from order total and shipping. 
Also I know Magento provides vat validation and removal from configuration but that only works for logged in customers.

Screenshot: https://nimb.ws/8ZEyVB

Comment: Please attachment screenshot

Comment: @MohitPatel Question updated. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now. Used Magento's default vat options to verify and remove vat.
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html

Comment: Do this work on run-time on checkout for guest checkout.?

Comment: Yes, I remember it was working :)